# Removal of "Open Lapce Here" from context menu

Tags: performance, issue-tracking

First of all, I just wanted to mention that I am using the win10 context menu in win11. How I changed it from win11 context menu to win10 context menu, I don't remember. So, few days back I uninstalled Lapce from my lappy, but whenever I right-click anywhere on the desktop, an option for "Open Lapce Here" is also shown in the context menu. This doesn't happen what I right-click on files/folders.

Does anybody have a solution?

I didn't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

> I uninstalled Lapce

You shouldn't have done that.

---

Try to check out "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell" in the registry.